# prevent ubuntu 18.04 login screen from saying my key strokes back to me

Tags: 18.04, sound, login

[image]I'm sure there's an answer to this somewhere but I don't know the right key words to search for it.

At the login screen when I type my user name, for some inexplicable reason
ubuntu has decided that it's a good idea to repeat back to me at full volume the letters that I'm typing.     and then when I type my password, it says blah blah blah blah at full volume.    I can of course mute the sound by moving the sound slider, but (a) this kills sound for other applications and (b) when I turn sound back on and then reboot, there it is, talking to me at full volume, which means I can't use my computer in a meeting.        Is there some way to disable forever this most absurd of all 18.04 features?      Thanks very much!

In response to a response by @S_flash, I'm uploaded a screenshot of my Universal Access settings:   everything is switched off

Comment: The default in Ubuntu is **not** to say the characters of the login password. I think you have installed something or tweaked some setting to make it happen. Can you remember what you did or what happened before it started (to say the characters of the login password)?

Comment: I turned on 'screen reader' and it worked, when logged in, but was silent when at the login screen. So it should be something else.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus,   The speech happens intermittently, typically but not exclusively immediately after I log in.      I don't know what on earth I did.     After googling around for `screen reader` I purged `orca`.      since that appears to be the program that is talking to me, it *should* in principle fix the problem.    We'll see.

Comment: Good luck :-) Please let us know, if the problem is fixed (after a few weeks).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by purging `orca`

Answer (score 0):

**Settings** -> **Universal Access** : Disable\Off all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @S_flash.     Unfortunately, the suggestion doesn't help since everything has been switched off in Universal Access,  I've added a screenshot of the Universal Access settings to the original question.    Am I missing something?